# How can I write raw byte characters in Python string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I am to develop an app that sends raw binary data over a socket network.

I have been given the characters to be

> 0x53 0x69 0x75 0x64 0x69 0x5F 0x37 0x42 0x6D 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x01
>   0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

I've been told that the first few characters

> 0x53 0x69 0x75 0x64 0x69 0x5F 0x37 0x42

means

> Siudi_7B

also

> 0x6D 0x00

means

> 109

so in my code I have this

```
message = "Siudi_7B 109 1 1"
```

which is equivalent to

> 0x53 0x69 0x75 0x64 0x69 0x5F 0x37 0x42 0x6D 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x01 0x00

Now the last few bytes I've not been given the meaning. And I'm supposed to figure it out. I've really tried my best but nothing yet.

So in short, I kindly need to know the string equivalent of

> 0x01 0x00

and

> 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

Comment: Which version of Python? You can do it in either Python 2 or 3, but it's easier & cleaner in Python 3.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry i didn't add that. I use python 3.6 sir

Comment: I understand how "Siudi_7B" and 109 are encoded, but how does "Siudi_7B 109 1 1" correspond to `0x53 0x69 0x75 0x64 0x69 0x5F 0x37 0x42 0x6D 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x01 0x00`? How does `1 1` become `0x04 0x00 0x01 0x00`?

Comment: You can put that data into your program using a `bytes` string: `b"\x53\x69\x75\x64\x69\x5F\x37\x42\x6D\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"` And you can write that directly to your socket.

Comment: Thanks sir, you've shed more light on the issue. I'm going to see if i can get this to work with this hint. But still open to other opinions

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your problem is. If you just need to type that data into your script, use the b-string I just showed you. If you're getting data in the form of a text string like `"0x53 0x69 0x75 0x64 0x69 0x5F 0x37 0x42 0x6D 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00"`, or a list of numbers like `[0x53, 0x69, 0x75, 0x64, 0x69, 0x5F, 0x37, 0x42, 0x6D, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]`, we can show you how to convert that into a b-string.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the string `binary` from the socket, you `binary.decode()` to convert the input to a string. Similary, when you have a `string` to write to the socket, use `string.encode()` to convert it to binary.

Comment: The OP is sending & receiving binary data, not text. Encoding or decoding to UTF-8 isn't relevant to this task.

Comment: @PM2Ring: quoting from documentation: "one can create a string using the decode() method of bytes."

Comment: Well, yes, but `some_bytes.decode()` creates a text string from the bytes in `some_bytes` by decoding it using the default UTF-8 codec. That's pointless if those bytes aren't actually the UTF-8 encoding of some text string. And the OP's data clearly isn't UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, PM 2Ring's comment helped point me in the right direction.

So I figured the initail doc was wrong,

> 109 is not equivalent to 0x6D 0x00
>   109 is 0x31 0x30 0x39

So I'm just going to request more clarifications on the task. Thanks a lot everyone.

So in code I will have

```
message = b"\x31\x30\x39"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read module `binascii` or `codecs` if you want to know each characters hex.

```
import codecs,binascii
codes =[codecs.encode(i.encode(),"hex") for i in "Siudi_7B 109 1 1"]
print( codes )
bins  = [binascii.hexlify(i.encode()) for i in "Siudi_7B 109 1 1"]
print( bins )
for x in "Siudi_7B 109 1 1":
    print("{:5}".format(x),end="")
print()
print("0x"+" 0x".join([str(b.decode()) for b in  bins]) )
```